# Facebook not displaying birthdays in iPhone calendar

Tags: iphone, calendar, facebook

I have an iPhone 4S running iOS 6.1.3 and I would like to have Facebook events in my calendar (again). I have enabled sync in Settings->Facebook by giving Facebook access to the calendar.

The calendar has been configured to show both Facebook-events (activiteiten) and Birthdays.

[image]
[image]

Unfortunately the calendar doesn't show any Facebook event nor Facebook birthday. Only when I manually accept an event, it will show it in my calendar. I would love to see both events, but I care mainly about seeing the birthdays of my Facebook contacts.

Comment: Sounds like you r not syncing. And what do you mean with AGAIN ?

Comment: It might have worked before. Can you explain what you mean by sounds I am not syncing? If I overlooked a setting, I would love to know.